# Javascript JSONP on Googlechrome

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, jsonp

I have a code, from here:

http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/

I tested it on Firefox with two domains, it works perfectly. But when I tried it on Google Chrome I get this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:

and this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

I haven't tried it on IE yet, but it's not a big deal. I can't figure out what seems to be the problem, and I'm kinda new to this kind of stuff.

Note: I dont want to use JQuery

Comment: Can you provide us a minimal "working" example ?

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"` Makes it sound like the actual response wasn't valid JSON, can you check what the response is in the Network panel [or log it to the console]

Comment: here it is: parseRequest({"item_id":13,"price":15,"quantity":20});

Comment: http://rottenhouse.net78.net/test.php here is the link of my test site. as I said its working on firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: you should close the question considering that you got a response here http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/comment-page-1/#comment-664

Answer (score 0):

After spent some time on this, I discovered that my problem is not on my script , but its on my freewebhosting added script, then i tried to disabled their script, and it works fine, but anyways thank you guys.